# Should my question remain newb friendly, or be more generic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users, title

[Check if an ArrayList contains every element from another ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511655/check-if-a-list-contains-every-element-from-another-another-list)

I asked this question when I was learning about ArrayLists.  I remember it very well.  At the time, I did not know what a list was.  All I knew was ArrayList.  This question was very newb friendly to me.

There was an edit to change the title from asking about ArrayLists to lists, which I rolled back.  The same edit was then made by another person.

Although the question is still accurate, and more generic, I think it loses its clarity of communication to the newbs, who are the target of this question.

Should this title be more generic, or more targeted?

Comment: I'm thinking at the very least they should capitalize List in their title edits as it refers to the List class and child classes, if people want to be pedantic about it.

Comment: "Accurate" is better than "friendly"

Comment: I'm thinking that ArrayList might be slightly for searchability because it's specific to Java, and I'm of the impression that ArrayList is the most common use case anyway.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield both are accurate

Comment: "Accuracy" is a somewhat broad term when considering the range of learners we have here. Thus, without getting into semantics, the use of "friendly" here is actually a type of "accurate."  @Evorlor is correct about this.

Comment: My point is that editing to include both terms is a good solution, as it allows clarity for all, and searchability.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what isn't clear about that question title?

Comment: Difficult one. It is more correct to program against an interface when you don't specifically need an ArrayList, but ArrayList is what will be used in the vast majority of the time. In the interest of making the question easier to find to people who have not properly informed themselves and will be specifically searching how to do things with an ArrayList, I would say that the unedited title is more effective.

Comment: I think a lot of people upvoted that "'Accurate' is better than 'friendly'" comment without reading the question, as it doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why not both?

We could change the title to something like

> Check if a List (e.g. an ArrayList) contains every element from another List

This would make the question easy to find and understand for newbies and experts alike.

Comment: It's so common for a newb not to know context, and this statement is a great example "At the time, I did not know what a list was." Editing to include both terms is a good solution, as it allows clarity for all, and searchability.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're referencing an API directly from a superinterface (e.g. `Collection`) as opposed to the concrete implementation of `ArrayList`, then making it generic is an accurate change.

A beginner learning how to program Java should learn, right off the bat, that there's more than `ArrayList` out there, and that it's not *just* `List`s that know how to perform a `containsAll`.

Comment: People vary in how they learn and in the order in which they learn. For example, if you're self-bootcamping, the learning path will be quite circuitous. Therefore, @Makoto's statement here about how a beginner should learn does, while correct, pertains to some (perhaps students learning more formally) but not all.

Comment: @geekandglitter What you say apply for everything, literally, that have been said about the topic here. Any decision about the situation or chosen course of action pertains to some students but not all, be it keep ArrayList or not. So, what do you actually mean here, what is your point about this answer?

Comment: Making it more general carries the risks of (a) losing the potential of answers focused on the more specific context (which doesn't really apply here, but might apply in other cases) and (b) hurting discoverability or [so] search ranking, even by people who know an ArrayList is a Collection. One might not initially think to search for the more general context (or one might not know how general to go), or one could intentionally look for the more specific context. The latter problem could be partially addressed with a few duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I think question title should mention ArrayLists.

The answer can clarify whether the needed method (`.containsAll()`) is inherited from some higher interface.
Anyone typing a question like this in google doesn't already know what interface their desired method belongs to.

Leaving the beginner/nonbeginner disambiguation alone, - this is a question for someone who **doesn't yet know where the method they need for their ArrayList is defined**.